Question which should have the answer "it is impossible"
I asked that question: https://superuser.com/questions/1842310/collaborate-on-a-ms-word-document-while-prohibiting-word-online
It has been closed.
But it seems, by reading all the comments, that the answer is "It is impossible".
I think if anyone is wondering the same question, they'd be glad to have this answer.
Do you think we should re-open this question to answer that is impossible or let it closed?




Generally speaking, "this cannot be done (at present)" is a perfectly valid and useful answer to a question. That said, without seeing your question, if a question was closed for other reasons it may not be fixable to a point where reopening is possible

The default application absolutely shouldn’t be Word Online, it should be Word, if it was installed on the local system. Question should be modified so it can be undeleted, reopened, and then answered. It’s not eligible to undeleted

You also obviously cannot open a Word document with (SharePoint, OneDrive, or Azure) as none of those have the ability to open Word documents without an appropriate application installed.

Thanks for your replies.
I don't really understand what modifications of my question do you propose.

I am not making any suggestions because I don’t believe the question can be modified so it can be undeleted, and ultimately answered. Because as I pointed out the default behavior absolutely is NOT to use Word Online. That would only happen if Office wasn’t installed on the system. The rest of the applications you listed don’t have the capability to open Word documents. You were asked for information but you never modified your question to include that information

OK, thanks.
On my computer Office web is the default behavior (I'm pretty sure it is the same for my colleagues because IT set computers with the same config). So even if I change it, my colleagues will have the problem, if I ask everyone to modify their preferences, I can't be sure they will do it, so they can't break formatting.
Anyway, I better understand my mistakes on this subject now. Thank you.
